# Custom fonts not loading on other people's server

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, font-face

I am running the Joints-WP-CSS version 6 theme which uses Foundation.

I have @font-face’d the following fonts in my style.css file like below. However, I am the only person who can see the proper fonts (here is a screenshot: [http://erinstruble.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Screen-Shot-2020-03-09-at-13.16.36.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOv5q.png)). Other people are getting the fallbacks. Someone at Go-Daddy said they saw this error “DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://erinstruble.com/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/assets/styles/style.css.map”. How can I get these fonts to work properly for others?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "StudioFeixenSans-Book" !important;
    src: url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.eot")!important;
    src: url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.ttf") format("truetype")!important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "StudioFeixenSerif-Regular"!important;
    src: url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.eot")!important;
    src: url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.ttf") format("truetype")!important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: it's look ok from my end http://prntscr.com/rdvu0l

Comment: Your file paths look wrong.

Comment: @Earid yeah that's the fallback font - Arial. Not Studio Feixen Sans.

Comment: @HowardE do you know how I might be able to make them right?

Comment: @ErinStruble which website are you trying to use the font on?  Yours or on miyfood.com ?

Comment: You neeed to put the forn on the sit's directory & correct the font URL

Comment: @HowardE I am trying to use them on erinstruble.com. But I also have miyfood.com as another wordpress on the same cpanel account. So that is the full path.

Comment: is the "directory" this file path? "http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com" or this one? "/home/erinstruble/public_html". I've tried them in so many places. I first had a "fonts" folder in here http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/erinstruble.com.

Comment: That's not the path from cpanel... that's your file structure. you can most likely take out all of the `http://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/` on each line. What you have is your directory path.

Comment: Okay I did take that out. But they're still not loading on my phone or other computers. Here's a new example path: http://erinstruble.com/wp-admin/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSerif-Regular.woff2. For me, when I click that it prompts me to download the file.

Comment: Try by putting the font on root folder & call.

Comment: Clear your browser cache now... Especially if you have an iphone.

Comment: Use the local folder path for the font; you'll be running into a permissions issue here.

Comment: @NathanielFlick are you meaning something higher up? Like making a folder here? sftp://miyfood.com/home/erinstruble/public_html/webfont. I think I've tried one almost that high up.

Comment: @ErinStruble no I mean take the http out of it and refer to the directory as a relative path on the same server as the rest of your code. It's bad practice to use another website's font, and if you check the url you're using, it's not correct anyway so it won't work.

Comment: I fixed it by making some new folders and then using the following path: http://erinstruble.com/css/webfont/StudioFeixenSans-Book.eot. Not sure how to close this. But it's fixed!